# Checking of empty textbox

Tags: java, netbeans, authentication, jtextfield, messagebox

I am trying to show a messagebox when either the username or password textbox is empty but when I run the project the only textbox showing is "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Username or Password is incorrect");" Please help and Thank You!

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  String user=txtUsername.getText();
  char[] pass=txtPassword.getPassword();

  if(user == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Username Field is empty"); 
  } else if(pass==null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Field is empty");     
  } else {
    String sql="select * from account where username=? and password=?";

    try{
      pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(1,txtUsername.getText());
      pst.setString(2,txtPassword.getText());

      rs=pst.executeQuery();

      if (rs.next()) {
        GridlockMain a=new GridlockMain();
        a.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Username or Password is incorrect"); 
        txtUsername.setText(null);
        txtPassword.setText(null);
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JTextField.getText()` does not return `null` if you keep it empty. Try to check value using `isEmpty` method at `if` condition.

```
  String user=txtUsername.getText();// It return empty String "" 
                                    // even no data is entered.

  if(user.isEmpty){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Username Field is empty"); 
  }
  ......
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
if(!user.length() > 0){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Username Field is empty"); 
  }
else if(!pass.length > 0){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Field is empty");     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns an empty string "" compare the

```
StringUtils.isEmpty(txtUsername.getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with the text Validation process. I found a very easy way to test this. Here, instead of using `JOptionPane` to show a message to the user, I just didn't allow them to enter, or press the button. Here's my code:

```
//Validate whether user Has input some information:
                if(UserNameTA.getText() == null || UserNameTA.getText().trim().isEmpty()) 
                {
                    btnEnter.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Make a new JFrame for login
                    new ProfileHome().setVisible(true);
                    frame.dispose();
                }
                btnEnter.setEnabled(true);
```

I hope this at least guides you to your success.

Answer (score 0):

```
String user = txtUsername.getText();
String pw = txtPassword.getText();      

if(user.isEmpty() || (pw.isEmpty()))

{       
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Username or Password is incorrect" );
}
    else
{
   //proceed to query
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    if (user.length() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username Field is empty");
    } else if (pass.length() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Field is empty");
    }
```

Comment: I've never heard of a string being less than 0 characters long. And if you were to fix this, this answer would then be identical to subash's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20263060/369450) which makes this answer pointless.